# Windows batch exit option b with or without errorlevel

Tags: windows, batch-file, errorlevel

I'm newbie in using batch on Windows and have a question about the use of errorlevel.

I referenced [TechNet(Exit)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490902.aspx) and many examples on google.

Most of them used /b with %errorlevel% like this

```
if errorlevel 1 exit /b %errorlevel%
```

I wonder the difference between

```
if errorlevel 1 exit /b
```

and

```
if errorlevel 1 exit /b %errorlevel%
```

I think there are no difference because %errorlevel% is not changed. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Most of the time there should be no difference, but technically `exit /b %errorlevel%` is strictly worse than `exit /b` if what you want is to exit without changing the error level.

#### Analysis

`EXIT /B` without the optional errorlevel parameter does not change the error level, so as a standalone command it is exactly equivalent to `EXIT /B %errorlevel%` *provided that `%errorlevel%` resolves to the current error level*.

But there are cases where it might not do so:

- If an environment variable named `ERRORLEVEL` is defined then `%errorlevel%` always resolves to its value (which can be arbitrary), and not to the current error level.
- If command extensions are disabled then `%errorlevel%` will never resolve to the current error level (it will still read the value of the environment variable with that name, if defined). You can verify this by starting a command prompt with `CMD /E:OFF` and trying `ECHO %errorlevel%`.
- The current error level value as produced by `%errorlevel%` will be fixed at the time the command is parsed, not at the time execution reaches that expression. This can result in the wrong value being produced for more complex commands. Example:

  ```
  copy j:\not_existing q:\not_existing & echo %errorlevel%
  ```

  This will not produce the same result as

  ```
  copy j:\not_existing q:\not_existing
  echo %errorlevel%
  ```

  because in the first case `%errorlevel%` will not produce the updated error level caused by the failed `copy`.

Comment: The last item could be solved by enabling and applying [delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) using `copy j:\not_existing q:\not_existing & echo !errorlevel!`…