# Difference between "|| exit /b" and "|| exit /b !errorlevel!"

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

We have a bunch of `.bat` build scripts which are invoked by a PowerShell based GitLab runner that were recently refactored from:

```
program args
if !errorlevel! neq 0 exit /b !errorlevel!
```

to the more succinct:

```
program args || exit /b
```

Today I investigated a build job which obviously failed if you looked at the error log but which was reported as a success. After much experimentation I discovered that this pattern didn't *always* work as expected:

```
program args || exit /b
```

but this did appear to work when the former didn't:

```
program args || exit /b !errorlevel!
```

---

I've read the SO question [Windows batch exit option b with or without errorlevel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158694/windows-batch-exit-option-b-with-or-without-errorlevel) and the statement below from https://www.robvanderwoude.com/exit.php but still can't quite explain what I'm observing.

> The DOS online help (HELP EXIT) doesn't make it clear that the /B parameter exits the current instance of script which is not necessarily the same as exiting the current script.
> I.e. if the script is in a CALLed piece of code, the EXIT /B exits the CALL, not the script.

---

This is the minimal batch file I used to explore this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cmd /c "exit 99" || exit /b
:: cmd /c "exit 99" || exit /b !errorlevel!
```

And this is how I invoked the batch file (to simulate how it was invoked by the GitLab PowerShell based runner):

```
& .\test.bat; $LastExitCode
```

Here is the output depending on which of the two lines in the batch file is executed:

```
PS> & .\test.bat; $LastExitCode
0
PS> & .\test.bat; $LastExitCode
99
```

---

There is another way to get the correct behaviour which is to invoke the batch file longhand from within PowerShell using `CALL` as well:

```
PS> & cmd.exe /c "call .\test.bat"; $LastExitCode
99
```

While I appreciate that this may be *the correct way* to invoke a batch file from PowerShell, that does not appear to be common knowledge based on the many examples I've seen. Also I wonder why PowerShell doesn't invoke a batch file this way if it's "the right way". Lastly I still don't understand why, when leaving off the `call`, the behaviour changes depending on whether we add the `!errorlevel!` to the `exit /b` statement.

---

**UPDATE:** Thanks for all the discussion so far but I feel it's getting lost in the weeds which is probably my fault for being too vague in my original question. What I think I'm really after (if possible) is **a definitive statement** about when the `errorlevel` is (supposedly) evaluated in the following statement:

```
program || exit /b
```

Is it really evaluated early (i.e. before `program` is run) like this:

```
program || exit /b %errorlevel%
```

Or is it evaluated lazily (i.e. when `exit` is being executed after `program` has run and internally `errorlevel` has been updated), more analogous to this:

```
program || exit /b !errorlevel!
```

Hence I'm not really after speculation unless, sadly, that is the best that we can do in which case knowing there is no definitive answer or that it's a bug is an acceptable answer to me :o).

Comment: You need the delayed expansion of `ErrorLevel`, otherwise, you get the value from a previous line(s), which would be zero in your case.

Comment: Thanks, this is not about `%errorlevel%` vs `!errorlevel!` it's about the use or absence of it with `exit /b`.

Comment: That's exactly what I said. Let put it another way: `exit /b` is equivalent to `exit /b %ErrorLevel%`, but that default behavior does not include delayed expansion.

Comment: The question though is if the implicit `%errorlevel%` when it's missing is actually evaluated at the same point (i.e. when the entire line is parsed) or if internally it behaves more like `!errorlevel!` as it's lazily evaluated when the `exit /b` is executed. What I'm asking is if _that_ behaviour is formally documented anywhere or are we just guessing?

Comment: Put another way I see many comments that suggest `exit /b` is equivalent to `exit /b %errorlevel%` but _do they actually mean that_, that the `errorlevel` is evaluated _early_ for a multi-part statement or are they being simplistic in their analogy? Given that `help exit` doesn't say another source would be helpful.

Comment: No, `exit /B` is not internally running `exit /B % ErrorLevel%`, rather it does not touch the `ErrorLevel` value; the problem is whose `ErrorLevel` or exit code is returned; I guess it is the one from `cmd.exe` rather than from your batch script…

Comment: > … but that default behavior does not include delayed expansion
--
@jwdonahue do you have a definitive source for that behaviour because that would be really useful, thanks.

Comment: > rather it does not touch the ErrorLevel value
--
Right, it doesn't _change_ `errorlevel` but it must evaluate it and it's the point of evaluation in a `prog || exit` statement that is the crux of my question.

Comment: Only the empirical evidence from the script I wrote to test it. I am considering how to make that answer more clear. I think `exit` behaves a bit differently when exit the script itself vs exiting a call. I am convinced that in your case, the script line must first be interpreted before the exit can happen, so either you get zero or you must use delayed expansion.

Comment: I will add that there have been many unintended behaviors in `command.com` and `cmd.exe`, and while Microsoft is loath to fix most of them, they also don't seem to want to document them either. The `::` bad label bug being used for comments comes to mind.  So I have gradually collected scripts that serve no purpose other than elucidating the actual behavior.

Comment: Also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/148991/3150445) might be important. Afraid I missed the fact that you were using `.bat` extension. I banned those wherever I've had sufficient control.

Comment: Thanks, I personally use `.cmd` by default but this codebase is a web of `.bat`s if I can mix my metaphors :o). I had forgotten about the differences but as `exit` is not in that list I presume it's not (intentionally) relevant.

Comment: Regarding your update: The definitive statement is: `program || exit /b` works like `program || exit /b !errorlevel!` (assuming `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`), but - with respect to setting the _`cmd.exe` process exit code_ - _only if your batch file is invoked with `call`_. Without `call`, `exit /b`'s error level unexpectedly does _not_ determine `cmd.exe`'s process exit code (it ends up `0`, even though _intra_-session the error level _is_ set, but that is irrelevant in your scenario). However, `exit /b <code>` - i.e. an _explicit_ exit code - _always_ sets `cmd.exe`'s process exit code.

Comment: So "Without `call`, `exit /b`'s error level unexpectedly does not determine `cmd.exe`'s process exit code" is what I'm taking away from all this. Many thanks for your patience!

Comment: I've updated my answer to recommend `cmd /c "<batch-file> ... & exit"` as the most robust workaround, because `cmd /c call <batch-file> ...` has the unavoidable side effect of doubling `^` characters in arguments - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66975883/45375) for details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Workarounds**:

- **Call your batch file via `cmd /c "<batch-file> ... & exit"`**, in which case the `|| exit /b` solution *without an explicit exit code* works as expected:

  - `cmd /c ".\test.bat & exit"`

    - If needed, escape any *embedded* `"` characters as `` `" ``, such as around batch-file paths and pass-through arguments that contain spaces: 
      `` cmd /c ".\test.bat `"quoted argument`" & exit" ``
    - Alternatively, if you don't need PowerShell's string interpolation to embed variable values in the call, you can use `'...'` quoting, in which case embedded `"` can be used as-is: 
      `cmd /c '.\test.bat "quoted argument" & exit'`
  - **Using `cmd /c "<batch-file> ... & exit"` *routinely* to call batch files from outside `cmd.exe` is advisable**, as even batch files *without* explicit `exit /b` (or `exit`) calls can otherwise behave unexpectedly - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55290133/45375).
- Alternatively - but only if your batch file never needs to be called *from another batch file* to which control should be returned and if it never needs to be part of a `cmd /c` *multi*-command command line where it isn't the *last* command<sup>[1]</sup> - you can use `|| exit` instead of `|| exit /b` - this exits the executing `cmd.exe` process *as a whole*, instantly, but the exit code (error level) *is* then reliably reported (at least in the context of a `<command> || exit` statement) also with *direct* invocation from outside `cmd.exe`, such as `& .\test.bat` (or, in this simple case, just `.\test.bat`) from PowerShell.

While combining `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` with `exit /b !ERRORLEVEL!` works too (*except* inside `(...)` - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67729271/45375)) - due to using an *explicit* exit code - it is obviously more cumbersome and can have side effects, notably quietly removing `!` characters from commands such as `echo hi!` (while it's possible to minimize that problem by placing the `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` call on the line just before an `exit /b` call, that would require duplication if there are multiple exit points).

---

**`cmd.exe`'s behavior is unfortunate** in this case, but can't be avoided.

When calling a batch file from outside `cmd.exe`:

- **`exit /b` - *without* an exit-code (error-level) argument - only sets the `cmd.exe` *process exit code* as expected - namely to the exit code of the *most recently executed command* in the batch file - *if you follow the batch-file call with `& exit`***, i.e. as `` cmd /c <batch-file> ... `& exit ``

  - *Without* the `& exit` workaround, an argument-less `exit /b` call from a batch file *is* reflected in the `%ERRORLEVEL%` variable *intra-`cmd.exe`-session*, but that doesn't translate to `cmd.exe`'s *process* exit code, which then defaults to `0`.<sup>[1]</sup>
  - *With* the `& exit` workaround, intra-batch-file argument-less `exit /b` *does* properly set `cmd.exe`'s exit code, even in a `<command> || exit /b` statement, in which case `<command>`'s exit code is relayed, as intended.
- **`exit /b <code>`, i.e. passing an exit code `<code>` *explicitly*, *always* works**<sup>[2]</sup>, i.e. the `& exit` workaround is then *not* needed.
- This distinction is an **obscure inconsistency that could justifiably be called a bug**; [Jeb's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66258887/45375) has sample code that demonstrates the behavior (using the less comprehensive `cmd /c call ...` workaround as of this writing, but it applies equally to `cmd /c "... & exit"`).

---

<sup>[1] With `cmd /c`, you can pass *multiple* statements for execution, and it is the *last* statement that determines the `cmd.exe` process' exit code. E.g, `cmd /c "ver & dir nosuch"` reports exit code `1`, because the non-existent file-system item `nosuch` caused `dir` to set the error level to `1`, irrespective of whether or not the preceding command (`ver`) succeeded. The inconsistency is that, for a batch file named `test.bat` which exits with `exit /b` *without an explicit exit-code argument*, `cmd /c test.bat` always reports `0`, whereas `` cmd /c test.bat `& exit `` properly reports the exit code of the *last statement executed before the batch file exited*.</sup>

<sup>[2] The exit code may be specified literally or via a variable, but the pitfall is that - due to `cmd.exe`'s up-front variable expansion - `<command> || exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%` does *not* work as intended, because `%ERRORLEVEL%` at that point expands to the error level *prior* to this statement, not to the one set by `<command>`; this is why *delayed* expansion, via having run `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` or having invoked the `cmd.exe` with the `/V` option, is necessary in this case: `<command> || exit /b !ERRORLEVEL!`</sup>

Comment: I built the sample code, because I didn"t believed your claims, but you are right!

Answer (score 8):

There is a difference between `exit /b` and `exit /b <code>`.
As mklement0 states, the difference becomes visible when calling a batch file with or without `CALL`

In my tests, I used `(call)` to force the errorlevel to 1.

**test1.bat**

```
@echo off
(call)
exit /b
```

**test2.bat**

```
@echo off
(call)
exit /b %errorlevel%
```

Testing with **test-all.bat**:

```
cmd /c "test1.bat" & call echo      Test1 %%errorlevel%%
cmd /c "call test1.bat" & call echo call Test1 %%errorlevel%%
cmd /c "test2.bat" & call echo      Test2 %%errorlevel%%
cmd /c "call test2.bat" & call echo call Test2 %%errorlevel%%
```

Output:

```
     Test1 0  
call Test1 1  
     Test2 1  
call Test2 1
```

To get an always reliable errorlevel, you should use the explicit form of `exit /b <code>`.
In case of using the construct `<command> || exit /b !errorlevel!` the delayed expansion is necessary or the form

```
<command> || call exit /b %%errorlevel%%
```

**Another solution**

```
<command> || call :exit
...

:exit
(
   (goto) 2>nul
   exit /b
)
```

This uses the *batch exception handling*
[Does Windows batch support exception handling?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31445330/463115)

Comment: I've updated my answer to recommend `cmd /c "<batch-file> ... & exit"` as the most robust workaround, because `cmd /c call <batch-file> ...` has the unavoidable side effect of doubling `^` characters in arguments (as you're well aware of) - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66975883/45375) for details.

Answer (score 5):

Let's look at the three possible scenarios:

```
cmd /c "exit 99" || exit /b
```

returns `0` because `cmd /c "exit 99"` executed correctly

```
cmd /c "exit 99" || exit /b !errorlevel!
```

returns `99` because `cmd /c "exit 99"` set `errorlevel` to 99 and we are returning the errorlevel which *results* from executing `cmd /c "exit 99"`

```
cmd /c "exit 99" || exit /b %errorlevel%
```

returns `?` - errorlevel as it was when the `cmd /c "exit 99"` line was parsed as it was
at that time  that `%errorlevel% was evaluated.

If `delayedexpansion` was **not** set, then the only difference is that the `!errorlevel!` scenario attempts to assign a string to the error level, which most probably won't work very well.

As for Powershell - it's a corner case on a road less travelled. A scenario that was not tested thoroughly as the designers expected to execute `.exe`s, etc. using this facility. No doubt even if it is reported, it would not be fixed as there's a workaround, even if it's not well-exposed.

This is, I believe, the fail-to-fail scenario - a facility that's assumed to work because the right conditions to cause it to fail are rarely met.

In the same way,

```
echo %%%%b
```

is ambiguous. Does it mean to `echo` the literal `%%b` or to `echo` `%` prefixed to the contents of metavariable `b`? (Answer : the latter). Not exactly encountered every day. What chance that the ambiguity will be resolved - ever? We can't even get `/u` implemented  on the `date` command to have it deliver the date in a universal format which would solve the vast majority of date-oriented questions posted on the `batch` tag. As for the possibility of a switch to allow `date` to deliver days-since-some-epoch-date - I haven't even bothered to suggest it since, despite inviting suggestions for `cmd` modifications, absolutely **nothing** has been done about facilities offered, just user-interface changes. Off playing with all the shiny things while ol' faithful languishes in the bottom of a locked filing cabinet stuck in a disused lavatory with a sign on the door saying ‘Beware of the Leopard.”

Comment: `cmd /c "exit 99"`, while executing correctly, still sets its process exit code to `99`, as explicitly requested, which you can see by running `echo %ERRORLEVEL%` afterwards. `exit /b` by itself _does_ pass this exit code through as expected, but the `cmd.exe` process as a whole inexplicably doesn't report it _unless_ the enclosing batch file was invoked with `call` (which, is _implicitly_ used when you invoke a batch file from cmd.exe itself interactively). PowerShell is not to blame here, and neither are the .NET APIs it uses behind the scenes.

Comment: @mklement0 If that were the case then I'd expect `exit /b` and `exit /b !errorlevel!` to behave the same, because in neither case was the `.bat` file invoked with `call`.

Comment: @ChrisOldwood, no, the _explicit_ use of an exit code is what makes all the difference with respect to `exit /b`: _with_ an explicit exit code  (whether specified literally or via a variable), the process exit code _is_ properly set; _without one_, the process exit code always ends up `0` instead of reporting the exit code of the most recently executed command (even on the LHS of `||`) - the latter happens  _only with `call`_, and that is the inconsistency at hand, which could justifiably be called a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Eliminating the irrelevant PowerShell and Cmd.exe invocation complexities so we can see how the cmd interpreter works:

```
@setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
@set prompt=$G

call :DefaultExit
@echo %ErrorLevel%

call :ExplicitExit
@echo %ErrorLevel%

@rem ErrorLevel is now 2

call :DefaultExit || echo One-liner ErrorLevel==%ErrorLevel%, not zero!
@echo %ErrorLevel%

@rem Reset the errorlevel to zero
call :DefaultExit
@echo %ErrorLevel%

call :ExplicitExit || echo One-liner ErrorLevel==!ErrorLevel!
@echo %ErrorLevel%

@exit /b

:DefaultExit
exit /b

:ExplicitExit
exit /b 2
```

Yields:

```
> test

>call :DefaultExit

>exit /b
0

>call :ExplicitExit

>exit /b 2
2

>call :DefaultExit   || echo One-liner ErrorLevel==2, not zero!

>exit /b
One-liner ErrorLevel==2, not zero
2

>call :DefaultExit

>exit /b
2

>call :ExplicitExit   || echo One-liner ErrorLevel==!ErrorLevel!

>exit /b 2
One-liner ErrorLevel==2
2
```

As you can see, `exit /b` is exactly equivalent to `exit /b %ErrorLevel%`, which is NOT what you want with your `||` failure execution path. You must invoke delayed expansion to get the results from the left side of the `||` operator.

---

I ran one more quick test of the above script and interactively checked the error level from the console window after the script exited:

```
> echo %errorlevel%
2
```

As you can see, `exit /b` alone, returned `2`, which was the previously set error level. So my hunch seems correct. You definitely require delayed expansion of some form `!ErrorLevel!` or `%^ErrorLevel%` (as per @aschipfl).

Comment: In batch files, `exit /b` is _not_ equivalent to `exit /b %ErrorLevel%`: It is _in effect_ equivalent to `exit /b 0` when the batch file is invoked _without_ `call` (`call` is used _implicitly_ in interactive invocations from `cmd.exe`). When invoked _with_ `call`, it correctly and dynamically picks up the exit code of the LHS operand of an `||` operation.

Comment: @mklement0, I'll let the empirical evidence speak for itself.

Comment: @mklement0 Sorry but the opening part of my question explicitly states that this is not the case, that `program args || exit /b !errorlevel!` works even without the use of `call`. This is why I'm confused :o).

Comment: @ChrisOldwood, the only reason why that works is that an _explicit_ exit code is used - that, without `call` - `exit /b` with _no_ explicit code does _not_ work, is the inconsistency at hand. If you want the convenience of argument-less `exit /b`, with the exit code being _implied_ by the most recently executed command (even if on the LHS of `||`), your only option is to use `call`. The other convenient option is to use just `exit`, but that prevents your batch files from being called by other batch files if control is to be returned to the latter. All that is explained in my answer.

Comment: @jwdonahue, your evidence is incidental to the problem at hand, which is _all about_ the invocation complexities from _outside_ `cmd.exe` (that it is PowerShell, specifically, calling, is incidental too).

Comment: P.S.: The empirical evidence that _does_ matter is in [Jeb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66258887/45375).

Comment: @mklement0, I disagree. The OP's example launches `cmd.exe` from a script. Converting from the `if...` format in the batch script, to the `||` operator style prompted the question due to the misunderstanding of how `cmd.exe` processes that line within the script.

Comment: @mklement0, actually, I think you and Jeb covered it better than I did.

Answer (score 1):

The `&` operator of PowerShell internally invokes `cmd.exe /C` when running a batch file. I bet `$LastExitCode` refers to invocation of `cmd.exe` rather than to the batch file. In this context, `call` passes over the `ErrorLevel` from the batch file to `cmd.exe`.

The same issue arises in `cmd.exe` (with PowerShell not involved at all), running `.\test.bat & call echo %^ErrorLevel%` does not invoke `cmd.exe /C` to run the batch file, so this works (meaning it always returns `99`). However, `cmd /C .\test.bat & call echo %^ErrorLevel%` just fails like your PowerShell attempt (returning `0` with your batch file as it stands), and `cmd /C call .\test.bat & call echo %^ErrorLevel%` succeeds and therefore returns `99`.

By the way, `call echo %^ErrorLevel%` just enables us not having to use delayed expansion.

Comment: > The `&` operator of PowerShell internally invokes `cmd.exe /C` -- does it just use `cmd /c` or does it supply any other switches? I've not found a definitive source for what PowerShell does and just wanted to check that my "emulation" was correct.

Comment: aschipfl, yes, it is the exit code of the `cmd.exe` process that is reported in `$LASTEXITCODE`, which also applies if you invoke a batch file _directly_, by assigning its path (perhaps surprisingly) _as-is_ as the `FileName` property of the [`System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo) instance PowerShell uses behind the scenes. That is, `cmd /C` is _not_ used, though if it were, the result would be the same. @ChrisOldwood, this also implies that no other switches are passed.

Comment: `call` is indeed what makes the difference here, and causes `cmd.exe`'s exit code and therefore `$LASTEXITCODE` to be set as expected even with an `exit /b` call _without an explicit exit code_, so `cmd /c call .\test.bat; $LASTEXITCODE` will do. As an aside re your attempt to have `cmd.exe` echo the exit code: your command doesn't actually work from PowerShell: first, you'd have to escape the `&` , but neither `%^ERRORLEVEL%`  nor `%ERRORLEVEL%` would work as expected; you'd have to use `cmd /v /c call test.bat \`& echo !ERRORLEVEL!`

Comment: @mklement0, `cmd /C call .\test.bat & call echo %^ErrorLevel%` was not intended to work with PowerShell, I just used it to demonstrate that the issue has nothing to do with PowerShell. Your suggestion `cmd /V /C call test.bat \`& echo !ErrorLevel!` constitutes a different situation, because `echo` executes *in* the context of `cmd /V /C`, where the `ErrorLevel` of course still exits, but the issue is the transfer of the `ErrorLevel` *beyond* `cmd`…

Comment: True, the issue has nothing to do with PowerShell, just with how `cmd.exe` sets its _process_ exit code when its CLI (`/c`) is used to execute a batch file - and it misbehaves  unless `call` is explicitly used. I now see what your command does: it just another way to show the same problem, only in the context of a `cmd.exe` session. Even though the problem isn't PowerShell-specific, what the OP is looking for is a solution in the context of PowerShell (which is `cmd /c call test.bat`, which causes `$LASTEXITCODE` to be set correctly), so I was confused by your sample command.

Comment: As an aside: I've since realized that the inconsistency around setting `cmd.exe`'s process exit code with CLI invocation is more fundamental than just `exit /b`, which leads me to conclude that using `cmd /c call` is generally the safest way to invoke batch files - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55290133/45375).